# How to change background color of table row if quantity column has numeric value less than 10

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am implementing cloth shopping website in which stock is added to the database by admin and admin can view, update and delete stock as well. while displaying record in table from the database I want that the item from stock thats quantity becomes 10 or less than 10 that row color becomes red so that it should be alert for admin that particular stock quantity is low.

**CODE:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Sr.No</th>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Image</th>
    </tr> 
    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM add_stock ORDER BY id DESC; 
    $rs_result = mysqli_query ($query);
    while ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result) )
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['brand_name'];</td>
            <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['gender_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['category_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['material_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['size_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $result['image'] ?>','mypopuptitle', '_parent')" >View Image</a></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myTable tr td').each(function(){
  var cellValue = $(this).html();
  if(!isNaN(parseFloat(cellValue))) {
    if (cellValue <= 10) {
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
    } 
  }
});  
</script>
```

---

this is my css code:

```
table {  
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    border-collapse: 
    collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

td, th {  
    border: 1px solid; /* No more visible border */
    height: 30px; 

    transition: all 0.3s;  /* Simple transition for hover effect */
}

th {  
    background: #DFDFDF;  /* Darken header a bit */
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
}

td {  
    background: #FAFAFA;

     height: 40px;
}

/* Cells in even rows (2,4,6...) are one color */        
tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #F1F1F1; }   

/* Cells in odd rows (1,3,5...) are another (excludes header cells)  */        
tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #FEFEFE; }  

tr td:first-child:before
{

counter-increment: Count-Value;
content: "" counter(Count-Value);
}
```

Comment: You aren't applying parseFloat() to cellValue when you compare it with <= to 10

Comment: Also there's no need to have two if statements there, use && operaters

Answer (score 0):

Why use `javascript` when you can handle that by `php`

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM add_stock ORDER BY id DESC; 
            $rs_result = mysqli_query ($query);
               while ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result) )
        {
          ?>
        /*Check if qty is less then 10 echo style=background-color:red*/
          <?php qty = (int)$result['dress_quantity']; ?>                    
          <tr <?php if(qty<10){echo 'style=" background: red !important;"';} ?>>
            <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['brand_name'];</td>
            <td><?php echo $result['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['gender_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['category_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['material_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['size_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['dress_quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $result['image'] 
       ?>','mypopuptitle', '_parent')" >View Image</a></td>

          </tr>
   </table>

          <?php
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: @ShoaibSharoon how about now, i added (int) so the database output would be converted to int

Comment: @Nana Partykar please check and anwser

Comment: how i can show? i don't know please guide i am new to stack overflow

Comment: inspect element in you navigateur then copie the html of the tr that must be red

Comment: i am also using css:

Comment: @ShoaibSharoon, i see what happend you have an background already

Answer (score 0):

You can echo `bgcolor` or a css class into the `<tr>` tag.

`<tr <?php if($result['dress_quantity'] < 10){ echo "bgcolor='#FF0000';} ?>`

Comment: you copied my answer : p

Comment: and you forget to add style=""

Comment: html supports bgcolor in this context. check this out [link](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_tr_bgcolor.asp)

Comment: ^^', i missed that

Answer (score 0):

You better add a class to the cells with quantity like `<td class="qty">` and then query for them like

```
document.querySelectorAll(".qty")
        .forEach(td => +td.textContent < 10 && (td.parentElement.sytle.backgroundColor = "red"));
```